# jQuery insertAt

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert an li element into a specific index on a ul element using jQuery. I only seem to be able to insert an element on the end of the list. I am very new to jQuery, so I may just not be thinking properly.

Comment: What about insertAfter() and insertBefore(): http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ & http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#thelist li").eq(3).after("<li>A new item</li>");
```

With the `eq` function, you can get a specific index of the elements retrieved...then, insert the new list item after it.

In the above function, I am inserting a new item at position 4 (index 3).

More info about the function at the [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index)

Comment: Hey you changed your name! (sorry I just noticed ^^)

Comment: hehe yup, I added my surname to my name =)

Comment: This approach unfortunately does not permit adding an item at index 0.

Comment: @Andrew: Adding an item to index `0` can be easily achieved with the [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method.

Answer (score 21):

A simple jQuery plugin ([a small test suite](http://jsfiddle.net/KQqfB/1/)) which permits adding an item at any index including 0.

```
$.fn.insertAt = function(index, $parent) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (index === 0) {
            $parent.prepend(this);
        } else {
            $parent.children().eq(index - 1).after(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming we have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Then inserting an item at index 0 `$('<li>C</li>').insertAt(0, $('#items'))` will result in

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>C</li>
    <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Inserting another item, this time at index 1 `$('<li>B</li>').insertAt(1, $('#items'))` yields

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>C</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

*Disclaimer:* there is no error handling of input parameters. If `index` is negative or greater than the length of children or if `index` is not a number the behavior is more or less undefined. If `$parent` is not a jQuery object `insertAt` will fail.

Comment: This should be the answer because it also covers the 0 index, what would not be possible with after or inserAfter.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Dreas's answer, but slightly different and possibly more efficient:

```
$("#thelist li:eq(2)").after("<li>new item</li>");
```

Or another way:

```
$("<li>new item</li>").insertAfter("#thelist li:eq(2)");
```

Comment: I like using eq as a selector also.  And this serves a nice explanation of the difference between after and insertAfter.

Answer (score -14):

Try to use this method.. it's the simplest way to insert text inside an element..

```
<div id="test"></div>

$('#test').append();
```