# How to move a row up or down in a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the JavaScript library [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to display data.

I want to be able to reorder the rows. I saw there was an extension called [RowReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) but it seems broken as even the examples found online don't reorder rows (at least in latest version of Chrome as of this writing).  And even if it worked, I don't like this solution because it is not clear that you can reorder the rows.

So I would like to implement something like the following image:

[image: DataTable reorder]

I found several links online asking for that but it seems nobody could make it work properly.

My data source is a simple array. No ajax yet. I want to start simple.

Is it something you've done before? Any direction on how to start building that feature?

Comment: You must do the coding yourself. Here is an example -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712227/datatables-row-add-to-specific-index/30782115#30782115 it is not quite the same, it is inserting a row at a specific position, but you should use same technique for moving rows up or down.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look and update the question as I get closer to the solution.

Comment: @davidkonrad I managed to make it work with code inspired from your answered. I did a +1 on that answer to thank you. Problem solved. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you to David Konrad for his guidance from his [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712227/datatables-row-add-to-specific-index/30782115#30782115) on how to add a row in the middle of a table.

The first thing I did is start by creating an `Action` column in my table and dynamically add the `Up` or `Down` options.

```
{
    name: 'action',
    data: null,
    title: 'Action',
    searchable: false,
    sortable: false,
    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
        if (type === 'display') {
            var $span = $('<span></span>');

            if (meta.row > 0) {
                $('<a class="dtMoveUp">Up</a>').appendTo($span);
            }

            $('<a class="dtMoveDown">Down</a>').appendTo($span);

            return $span.html();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then, I added code in the `drawCallback` to remove the `Down` arrow of the last row and bind the click event to `moveUp` and `moveDown` functions:

```
'drawCallback': function (settings) {
    $('#ArgumentsTable tr:last .dtMoveDown').remove();

    // Remove previous binding before adding it
    $('.dtMoveUp').unbind('click');
    $('.dtMoveDown').unbind('click');

    // Bind click to function
    $('.dtMoveUp').click(moveUp);
    $('.dtMoveDown').click(moveDown);
}
```

Then I coded the move up/down functions. It is important to note that my data has a `order` property that I use to change the order.  This `order` is displayed as the first column and makes it the default sort column:

```
// Move the row up
function moveUp() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    moveRow(tr, 'up');
}

// Move the row down
function moveDown() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    moveRow(tr, 'down');
}

// Move up or down (depending...)
function moveRow(row, direction) {
    var index = table.row(row).index();

    var order = -1;
    if (direction === 'down') {
      order = 1;
    }

    var data1 = table.row(index).data();
    data1.order += order;

    var data2 = table.row(index + order).data();
    data2.order += -order;

    table.row(index).data(data2);
    table.row(index + order).data(data1);

    table.page(0).draw(false);
}
```

**Note**: It is important to understand that when you ask DataTable to `draw()` your table again, it will use your data to sort the results according to the parameters set in the DataTable definition.  This is why I chose, for this example, to set the `order` as the first column (default sort) and alter my data objects directly (instead of playing with internal information from DataTable). That makes things a lot easier.

**Note 2**: It is **really** important that your data is received by the DataTable already sorted by `order`. Otherwise, this solution won't work as is.

You can check a full working example here:

**https://jsfiddle.net/kxfx489y/4/**

Comment: Fabulous, I have enable paging and added records more than 10. Even then this solution is working. the only thing which should be changed table.page(0).draw(false); to table.draw(false);

Comment: the following code will show the Up button only on last page not on every page.
let pageInfo = $('#ArgumentsTable').DataTable().page.info();
            //console.log(pageInfo);
            if (pageInfo.page + 1 === pageInfo.pages) {
                $('#ArgumentsTable tr:last .dtMoveDown').remove();
            }