# New conditional row in DT with rowCallback in R shiny

Tags: jquery, r, datatable, shiny, dt

I would like to introduce a new row in the DT when some condition is met. It is for presentation purposes.

For example, if the first column has the value "General risk" in some row, then a new row with only one column is introduced before. The new column will have the value "RISKS". I have the following rowCallback:

```
rowCallback = I(
                'function(row, data) {
                   if (data[1] == "General risk")
                     $("tr", row).prepend("<tr><td>RISKS</td></tr>");
                }'
               )
```

The line `$("tr", row).prepend("<tr><td>RISKS</td></tr>");` doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to [official docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712227/datatables-row-add-to-specific-index) there is no API method in `datatables` (`DT` package in R) for adding rows at specific indeces.

You can solve this via `rowCallback` in JavaScript, but I would suggest creating a temporary `data.frame` in R (can be a reactive, it depends on your use case).

#### Code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# Create df for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(
  test = c("General risk", "Category2", "Category3"),
  some_value = runif(12)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable( {
    # Create temporary data.frame
    df_shown <- df

    # Row indeces to add
    row_indeces <- which(df$test == "General risk")

    # Add rows in decreasing order
    for (i in sort(row_indeces, decreasing = TRUE)) {
      df_shown <- dplyr::add_row(df_shown, test = "Risk", some_value = NA_real_, .before = i)
    }    


    datatable(
      data = df_shown,

      # Change bg color to stand out more
      options = list(
        rowCallback = JS("
          function( row, data, index ) {
            if (data[1] === 'Risk') {
              $(row).css('background-color', 'Crimson');
            }
          }"
        )
      )
    )
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. The solution that are you commenting was my last option if  I couldn't do it with javascript. I saw the row.add() but I don't get with the desired result.

Comment: @FrancescVE I wouldn't bother with JavaScript in this case, as you have some better tools in R, and there is not much benefit over the R solution.