# Change the order of the element during of creating it on fly way by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I insert the element at a specific location in the parent during of creating it on fly for example:

My json array:

```
var arrayAttributes = {
        "parent": [{ "isObj": false, "sortHTML": "div", "class": "col-sm-6 activePage"}],
        "header": [{ "sortHTML": "label", "text": "Status"}],
        "input": [{ "id": "activePage", "type": "checkbox", "class": "activePage", "checked": isChecked, "value": me.activate, "index": "1"}],
        "label": [{ "class": "activePage", "forLabel": "activePage", "text": inputTxt, "hasChild": false}]
    };
```

creating the HTML element by json array:

```
(arrAttr.input ?
                 $("<input:eq( "+arrAttr.input[0].index+" )/>", {
                    "id": arrAttr.input[0].id,
                    "class": arrAttr.input[0].class,
                    "type": arrAttr.input[0].type,
                    "checked": arrAttr.input[0].checked,
                    "value": arrAttr.input[0].value
                 }).appendTo(parent)
            : '');
```

If you notice I am using json array to set the attributes of my HTML elements, so I want also to set the location of  the elements depends on the value of "index" in my json array.

In the examples also I tried to use eq(n) function but it returned an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the label at a specific location in the parent?

Comment: Ja. if you notice I am using json array to set the attributes of my elements, so I want also to set the location of  the elements depends on the value of "order" in my json array.

Comment: what are you aksing.? please be specific.wht do you mean by order of element? how does it displayed on html? or is it related to iteration you are showing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution also in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391314/jquery-insertat) 
Please: if you have some notice add it for me!

So I can use this function instead of using appendTo().
I adjusted this function to be like that:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
insertAt: function (index, $parent) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (index == null) {
            $parent.append(this);
        }
        else if (index === 0) {
            $parent.prepend(this);
        }
        else {
            $parent.children().eq(index - 1).after(this);
        }
    });
}});
```

You can see that I just added extra if in the binning, so if you don't want insert "index" in your json array the function will append you HTML element in normal way. 
You can use the function like that:

```
(arrAttr.input ?
             $("<input:eq( "+arrAttr.input[0].index+" )/>", {
                "id": arrAttr.input[0].id,
                "class": arrAttr.input[0].class,
                "type": arrAttr.input[0].type,
                "checked": arrAttr.input[0].checked,
                "value": arrAttr.input[0].value
             })..insertAt(arrAttr.input[0].index, parent)
        : '');
```